# How to match a varying number of child elements for parents with the same class using XPath in HTML?

Tags: html, xpath

I have a webpage with the following structure, and I'm extracting data from it via XPath Helper Google Chrome extenson

```
<div class="example">
   <span class="name">John Doe</span>
   <span class="foo">1</div>
</div>
<div class="example">
   <span class="name">Jane Doe</span>   
</div>
<div class="example">
   <span class="name">Richard Roe</span>
</div>
<div class="example">
   <span class="name">Jane Roe</span>
   <span class="foo">2</div>
</div>
```

I want to use XPath to select `name` and `foo` of each example variable. If the variable doesn't have a `foo` value, it should display me `0`, `blank` or `NULL` so I can match each `name` with each `foo`

This query `//div[@class="example"]/span[@class="name"]` can return all the names

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
Richard Roe
Jane Roe
```

However with this query `//div[@class="example"]/span[@class="foo"]` I only get a result when `foo` exists

```
1
2
```

With the combination of those two queries alone I can't track which `foo` belongs to each `name` under the `example` div.

I ideally need a query which returns

```
John Doe, 1
Jane Doe, 0
Richard Roe, 0
Jane Roe, 2
```

However if I can get a query with only the second part

```
1
0
0
2
```

It'd work as well because I could match the results with the respective names.

How do I build a query to do this job with XPath 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 2.0 you could use a for loop as :

```
for $ex in //div[@class='example']
 return concat( $ex/span[@class='name'], ',', sum($ex/span[@class='foo'], '0'))
```

It returns :

```
John Doe,1
Jane Doe,0
Richard Roe,0
Jane Roe,2
```

Comment: For this task I'll be using the Chrome Extension XPath Helper. I failed to find documentation to assure which XPath version it supports. But since your function didn't work I assume it only works with XPath 1.0

Comment: @steps Is the html from a web page ?